# JavaFX: TreeTableView Selection Listener unexpected behaviour

Tags: javafx, listener, selection

I want to apply an listener to selection changes in my TreeTable View. Anyhow its behaviour is not like expected.

Here is my datamodel:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
public class File {
    private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
    public File (String name)            {nameProperty().set(name);   }
    public StringProperty nameProperty() {return this.name;   }
    @Override public String toString()   {return name.get().toString() ;}
}
```

And here is my main application:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TreeItemPropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class treeTableViewTest extends Application {
   @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {

       // DemoData =========================================================
       File rootFile = new File("/");
       TreeItem<File> child2 = new  TreeItem<File>(new File("Child 2"));

       TreeItem<File> root = new TreeItem<File>(rootFile);
       root.getChildren().add(new  TreeItem<File>(new File("Child 1")));
       root.getChildren().add(child2);
       root.getChildren().add(new  TreeItem<File>(new File("Child 3")));
       root.getChildren().add(new  TreeItem<File>(new File("Child 4")));
       root.getChildren().add(new  TreeItem<File>(new File("Child 5")));
       root.setExpanded(true);
       child2.getChildren().add(new  TreeItem<File>(new File("SubChild 1")));
       child2.getChildren().add(new  TreeItem<File>(new File("SubChild 2")));

       // Layout =========================================================
        final StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        TreeTableView<File> treeTable = new TreeTableView<>();

        treeTable.setEditable(true);
        treeTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        treeTable.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
        treeTable.setRoot(root);

        TreeTableColumn<File,String> fileNameCol = new TreeTableColumn<>("Filename");
        treeTable.getColumns().setAll(fileNameCol);
        fileNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory("name"));

        stackPane.getChildren().add(treeTable);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(stackPane,250,250));
        stage.show();

       // Selection Listener ================================================

        treeTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<TreeItem<File>>() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends TreeItem<File>> c) {
            while (c.next()) {
                 if (c.wasPermutated()) {
                         for (int i = c.getFrom(); i < c.getTo(); ++i) {
                              //permutate
                         }
                     } else if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                            System.out.println("updated: " + c.toString());
                     } else {
                         for (TreeItem<File>  remitem : c.getRemoved()) {
                             System.out.println("removed: " + remitem.toString());
                         }
                         for (TreeItem<File> additem : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                             System.out.println("added: " + additem.toString());
                         }
                     }
                 for(TreeItem<File> file :  c.getList() ){
                     System.out.println("  -> " + file.toString());
                 }
            }
        }});

     // Random Interactions =========================================================
          treeTable.getSelectionModel().select(3);
          treeTable.getSelectionModel().select(5);
          treeTable.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(1);

    }

   public static void main(final String[] args){
      launch(args);
   }
}
```

Since I have defined `treeTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);` I would expect that every time I select one item, all others automitically are deselected.

The output of my code is:

```
added: TreeItem [ value: Child 3 ]
  -> TreeItem [ value: Child 3 ]
added: TreeItem [ value: Child 5 ]
  -> TreeItem [ value: Child 5 ]
removed: TreeItem [ value: Child 5 ]
added: TreeItem [ value: Child 1 ]
  -> TreeItem [ value: Child 1 ]
```

I would have expected this output:

```
added: TreeItem [ value: Child 3 ]
  -> TreeItem [ value: Child 3 ]
removed: TreeItem [ value: Child 3 ]   // <- missing in original output
added: TreeItem [ value: Child 5 ]
  -> TreeItem [ value: Child 5 ]
removed: TreeItem [ value: Child 5 ]
added: TreeItem [ value: Child 1 ]
  -> TreeItem [ value: Child 1 ]
```

Why is the removed `Child 3` not directy seen in the listener? Obviously it has been removed since it was not in `c.getList()` anymore.

**Edit**

Issue is now sumitted as a bug report here:
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8175260

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not how this selection model works (it is `TreeTableViewArrayListSelectionModel`).

Despite being `ObservableList`, `selectedItems` property doesn't always notify you about its changes (it is implemented with `ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList` which doesn't provide any notifications - it is the selection model what creates and emits them).

If `SelectionMode == SINGLE`, the selection model, when being ordered to select another row, almost always performs `quietClearSelection` - which just removes all selections items without notyfying observers about that fact.

So, why does it work properly when manually clicking on the rows?
I have checked what method is called after a mouse click on a row - in case of `SelectionMode.SINGLE` it is always `clearAndSelect` method.

I am sure that this is a not documented contract, that when selection model is `SINGLE` all "users" should clear selection before selecting another row (since selecting two or more rows would be illegal).

In my opinion, with `SINGLE` selection model, you should observe `selectedItem` property - below you can find a working example:

```
treeTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TreeItem<File>>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TreeItem<File>> observable, TreeItem<File> oldValue, TreeItem<File> newValue) {
        System.out.println(oldValue + "->" + newValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear and coprehensive explaination, Maciej.

Comment: In my full code (not this small example) I found some strange behaviour, similar but not identical to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830075/javafx-exception-when-clicking-treetablecell-after-repopulating-treetableview/28716773   -- (even after changing the listener to your suggestion) I could solve it, applying `table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();` at each update of the table root / data. Seems that the selction model is a bit sensitive here.

Comment: Issue is now submitted as a bug report to oracle: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8175260